# Win32 STD_INPUT_HANDLE / ReadConsoleInput: How to write to it from Java?

Tags: java, winapi, input, console

I have a Windows process monitoring the stdin.

```
stdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
```

I'm waiting on stdin using WaitForMultipleEvent and I'm reading using ReadConsoleInput.

It works perfectly when I run my process from a Windows terminal (cmd.exe).
My process can see the various characters I'm typing.

So far, so good.

I have a Java process that spawns my Win32 executable and tries to write to it. My Windows processes detects NOTHING.
Here is a Java snippet:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdarray);
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
writer.append("quit"); //$NON-NLS-1$
writer.flush();
```

The Java spawns my process perfectly. However, the WiN32 processes never receives anything.
(I've tried to monitor stdin from a Linux process : In that case, it works, so my Java code is probably correct. It's the way I'm monitoring the stdin on Windows that does "fit" with Java...)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

SetConsoleMode (stdin, 0);
Use ReadFile instead of ReadInputConsole.